# Tool to search for dependencies of javascript variables and functions

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I must to refactor the project in which thousands of lines of js-code. Is there a tool to search for dependencies of global variables and functions in the project javascript-files? It would be desirable that the tool could construct a graph.

Comment: You should add some more info, e.g. if this is JS code written for nodejs (if so, try the [web-stats-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stats-graph) module), or javascript slapped into <script> tags inside .html files (If so, you are out of luck). Or is it a mess of jQuery methods chained together ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) on your project with the options set to include undocumented functions and to map dependencies *(ideally with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php) also installed)* and it will give you, in a variety of formats, all of the functions and globals with where they are used.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Works for multiple languages:

  - Java
  - C, C++, C#
  - Python
  - Fortan
  - IDL
  - VHDL

### Update

For JavaScript the doxygen site has the following to say:

> For those working with JavaScript it may be good to know that Jörg
>   Schaible has written a perl script to let doxygen deal with it.
>   Unfortunately his site at berlios.de has been removed. If you google
>   for js2doxy.pl you can still find copies of the script however.

This may or may not be of some help to you.

Comment: OP specifically asked for "JavaScript".  I don't see that in the list.

Comment: Sorry for the wait, we had some difficulty at work, which distracted me. Your decision looks complicated, I would prefer the NPM module. But in any case I will try to use it in the next week.

Comment: That was 7 months ago - how did it work out?